# Unable to echo PHP coded cookie value? 

Tags: php, cookies

I have the following code that builds a cookie:

```
$username = $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'];
    $pass = $_COOKIE['Key_my_site'];
    $firstName = $_COOKIE['firstName'];
    $lastName = $_COOKIE['lastName'];
    $active = $_COOKIE['active'];
    $email = $_COOKIE['emailAddress'];
```

then when using:

```
echo "<b>Username:</b> <? " . $username . "?>";
        echo "<a href=logout.php>Logout</a>";
```

The value is not printed as expected.

Can the community explain why and provide me with the correct method for echoing the value to the relevant output device?

Comment: The code you've given does not build a cookie, it reads from the [`$_COOKIE` array](http://php.net/$_COOKIE).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you never set $_COOKIE['ID_my_site'].  You could do a `print_r($_COOKIE);` to see what it contains.  I don't recommend using cookie like this,  its against RFC.  If you need to keep this information throughout the session then you should use $_SESSION.  This also keeps malicious people from changing their cookie.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using that syntax exactly, then you haven't echoed the variable at all.  Try:

```
echo "Username: $username"; 
echo "Logout";
```

I see you've edited your question.  If $username is not getting populated, try outputting all of $_COOKIE to see what's in there first.

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: Keep variables out of your string! Use `echo "Username: " . $username;` instead.

Comment: I find that the VERY slight performance hit I take on interpolating the variable is more than outweighed by the increased readability of the code.  YMMV.